# Change color of menu item on mouse hover

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of [the menu](https://buycrueltyfreemakeup.com/about/#) item to black on mouse hover but after several tries, I am unable to do so. Please guide me. Thanks.

```
.primary-nav .suppa_menu .suppa_top_level_link.current-menu-item, .primary-nav .suppa_menu .suppa_top_level_link.current-menu-ancestor{
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.primary-nav .suppa_menu:hover .suppa_top_level_link {

    background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
    color: #000000  !important;
}
.suppa_item_title:hover .suppa_menu a:hover .suppa_item_title:hover{
    color: #000000  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In primary-nav.css, the color of the text on hover is currently set as:

```
.primary-nav .suppa_menu:hover .suppa_top_level_link .suppa_item_title {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

If you change this to:

```
.primary-nav .suppa_menu:hover .suppa_top_level_link .suppa_item_title {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

it should work.